# How can I disable pywebkit console messages?

Tags: python, webkit

For example, how do I disable these messages, that appear on terminal?:

> ** Message: console message:  @1: Refused to set unsafe header "cookie"
>
> ** Message: console message:  @1: Refused to set unsafe header "cookie"

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but if it helps someone:
You can define a handler to `console-message`, something like:

```
self.webview.connect("console-message", self._javascript_console_message)
... 
def _javascript_console_message(self, view, message, line, sourceid):
    return True #True prevents calling original handler
```

Documentation:

http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-console-message